# ruby rspec: setting arbitrary constraints on mock object expectation method arguments

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

How do you constrain the allowable argument values passed to a method of a mock object in RSpec? (assuming an expectation has previously been set on that mock object)

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
@myMockObject.should_receive(:logValue).at_least(:once).with(anything(), should be > 0)
```

That is, I want to specify that @myMockObject receives a method call to logValue() with anything for the first argument and any integer greater than 0 for the second argument. Unfortunately, the above code does not work as written. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@myMockObject.should_receive(:log_value) do |arg1, arg2|
  arg2.should be > 0
end.at_least(:once)
```